# Wireless mouse driver won't work with my microsoft mobil 4000 mouse

Tags: 10.04, mouse

I installed Ubuntu 10.4 amd 64 today but the drivers for the mouse are terrible, the cursor moves so slow it's not usable. I've tried setting the speed of the mouse to top speeds but it didn't help at all. Any suggestions as to what I can do? Linux Newbe here. Thanks.

Comment: Same mouse, and it does not work. `xinput` shows 2 `Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v1.0` under `Virtual core pointer` as well as 2 non-existent keyboards! After a while the mouse becomes unbearably slow and unresponsive.